# How do I use luasocket from my VS C++ project, either find luasocket.h from LuaForWindows or build LuaSocket for Lua 5.2

Tags: visual-studio-2012, build, lua, luasocket

I had installed Lua 5.1 using LuaForWindows, but I don't see luasocket.h in what was installed, so it appears I can't use that from my Visual Studio C++ project.

So, I am trying to build and I got the latest version from github for Lua 5.2, even though it is in development as I can't find the source for Lua 5.1 from sourceforge.

When I go to http://luaforge.net/projects/luasocket/ it brings me back to the LuaSocket page.

So, I have built Lua 5.2.2 and this is my build.bat for luasocket:

```
set INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;C:\Users\me\Downloads\lua-5.2.2\src
echo %INCLUDE%
set LIB=%LIB%;C:\Users\me\Downloads\lua-5.2.2\src
echo %LIB%
ren unix.c unix.c00
ren usocket.c usocket.c00
cl /MD /O2 /W3 /c /nologo /DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN *.c
ren mime.obj mime.o
link /DLL /OUT:socket.dll /base:0x67800000 /export:luaopen_socket_core *.obj mime.o msvcrt.lib lua5.2.lib wsock32.lib
link /DLL /OUT:mime.dll /base:0x67700000 /export:luaopen_mime_core mime.o msvcrt.lib lua5.2.lib
```

The biggest problem is that `luaL_openlib undefined` appears when trying to compile some of the c files and `_luaL_openlib` is an unresolved external symbol referenced, but these are related issues.

I currently don't care if I use Lua 5.1 or 5.2, but I need to be able to use LuaSocket, so is there a way to use it from LuaForWindows (https://code.google.com/p/luaforwindows/) or is there a problem with my build.bat that will fix my problem?

Comment: Use LuaSocket how? There is a DLL in the **`clibs\socket\\`** directory.

Comment: @hjpotter92 - My C++ program is trying to include luasocket.h and that isn't found.  I will look to see if it can resolve the header file from the DLL, but I have my doubts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Updated on 10/2/2015) The changes described earlier have been merged into luasocket [master branch](https://github.com/diegonehab/luasocket/), which compiles with Lua 5.2 on Windows.

(previous version of the answer, which is no longer applicable)

You need to use [this branch](https://github.com/diegonehab/luasocket/tree/unstable) if you want to compile luasocket with Lua 5.2. It includes a solution file for VisualStudio.

I haven't compiled this branch with VisualStudio, but I did compile it with mingw and used it with Lua 5.2 on Windows.

Here is the list of build flags I have for mingw: `BUILD_FLAGS="-Wl,-s -O2 -shared -D LUA_COMPAT_MODULE -D IPV6_V6ONLY=27 -D WINVER=0x0501 -s`; I also link with `-lwsock32 -lws2_32 -llua`.

In your case I don't see `LUA_COMPAT_MODULE`, which is currently required by luasocket and also don't see `ws2_32` on the list of libraries.

I also ran into missing `inet_ntop` and `inet_pton` calls, so I [patched luasocket](https://github.com/pkulchenko/luasocket/commit/5a58786a39bbef7ed4805821cc921f1d40f12068) to include those (not sure if this an issue for VS as well). You may want to try compiling with this branch: https://github.com/pkulchenko/luasocket/commits/lua52-mingw.

Comment: I did use that branch, which is where I have the problem when I try to build it from scratch.

Comment: Any idea when your change will be in the unstable branch?

Comment: @JamesBlack, unfortunately, no idea. I'll send a pull request, but it's up to Diego to merge and release a new version.

Comment: FYI: these changes have been incorporated into luasocket 3.0 (available on github)

Comment: your "this branch" link is now a 404

Comment: @Epirocks, these changes have been merged into master branch of luasocket, so that `lua52-mingw` branch was no longer needed and removed to avoid confusion. I'll update the answer.